# Android studio source codes red errors

Tags: android, android-studio

[this image is aboout activity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BYyN.jpg)

Now you can see the res point.it really confused me!
How to solve this problem, I really want to see that class.
If you know how to solve it ,just do it.

Comment: Add those libraries in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Those unresolved imports refer to internal classes/interfaces that are not included in the SDK because they are not intended for public use.

If you want to view source code for those internal classes, you can just check them here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/

Answer (score 0):

This means that for those particular imports you need to import specific libraries which are not included in the SDK because they are not required for general use.